# How to formally express a function which is "dependent upon another function"

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions

Lets say I have the expression

$ a + b + c(d) + e$

where $a,b,d,e$ are variables and $c$ is a function. I now want to write the expression as a function

$y(a,b,?,e) = a + b + c(d) + e$

What replaces the `?` in the arguments? Is it `c(d)` or some combination of the two? Is it formally wrong to just say

$y = a + b + c(d) + e$

i.e. without the function arguments? I've read before that $y(\ldots) \neq y$, where the former is strictly a value and the latter is strictly a function.

I'm asking these questions because I have an expression that is very long, but I'm not 100% sure how I should write it. It's for a publication and I don't know if my own lose interpretation is going to fly. I'd rather get it right from the start.

Comment: Does $y$ take $c$ as input, or $d$, or both ? The answer to that will answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c$ is a fixed function, then you want to define $y$ as a function with inputs $a,b,d,e$ and output $a+b+c(d)+e$. So that is given by the defining equation $y(a,b,d,e) = a+b+c(d)+e$ for every $a,b,d,e$ in the desired domain. There should be no $c$ in the definition of $y$, because $c$ is not an input.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Just for clarity, what if `e` was a constant? Would that still be included in the function argument? Also can you comment on the $y(\ldots) \neq y$ part?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack: Yes, if any of $a,b,e$ are constants, you cannot include them in the function inputs, simply because they are already fixed/defined. What you said about the difference between "$y(\cdots)$" and "$y$" is correct; in rigorous modern mathematics they are not the same, in exactly the same manner that "the mass of" is different from "the mass of that rock".

Comment: By the way, I have no idea who downvoted your question, or why. I have upvoted it. There are many trolls on this site who downvote for no good reason, and I've been targeted before. Ignore them.

Comment: I know I already accepted the answer, but I ran into a couple other questions that I thought you could quickly help with. If $y(\ldots)$ is strictly a value, can I assign it to another variable, say $f = y(\ldots)$, where $f$ would be called a "variable" (because it is a value that changes) ? If true, define a new function that depends on that variable, $g(f)$, but given the equality, this is $g(y(\ldots))$, which looks like a function composition. So strictly speak $g(y(\ldots)) \neq g(y)$ because $y$ "is not an input". Does this logic agree with your answer? This is how compositions work?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack: No problem at all. You need to be careful with the entities you are dealing with. The standard mathematical way is that there are no "variables that change"; instead you use functions to capture any relation, for example $f(t)$ may be the value of some quantity at time $t$, where $f$ is a function whose domain is the set of valid times. Similarly here, if $y$ is a real function with one input from $D$, then $y(t)$ would be a real number for each $t∈D$. In any context where you have some $e∈D$, you can let $x = y(e)$, but that $x$ stays in that context.

Comment: For example, given any function $y : \Bbb{R}→\Bbb{R}$, you can define a new function $f : \Bbb{R}→\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(t) = y(3t)$ for each $t∈\Bbb{R}$, because for each $t∈\Bbb{R}$ we have $3t∈\Bbb{R}$ and so $f(3t)∈\Bbb{R}$. If you have more questions, feel free to ask [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics).

Comment: I know this is old, but can expand the answer a bit to tell me what you mean by "fixed function"?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack: If you want $y$ to be a function whose output depends on $c(d)$ where $c$ is not fixed, then $c$ would have to be an *input* to $y$.

Comment: I still don't fundamentally know what you mean by "fixed" vs "not fixed". In your answer you wrote $y(a,b,d,e) = a + b + c(d) + e$, which to me says the value of $y(a,b,d,e)$ is dependent upon the value of $c(d)$. By passing in $d$, we've provided the necessary input to $c$. This makes sense. But why do we not pass in $c$? You said it depends if $c$ is "fixed" or "not fixed". This is what I don't understand. Do you mean it's definition? So if I say $c(d) = d+2$ ... this can be "fixed" and used in $y()$ w/o being an argument. If $c(d)$ changes definition then I must pass it in?

Comment: OK...I think that makes sense now, but I'm going to check w/ you. The definition $y(a,b,d,e) = a + b + c(d) + e$ doesn't change. It's just a question of the definition of $c$. This analogy might be wrong, but it's like a "global constant" vs "local variable" in programming? The function $y$ can be defined as is, but if the function $c$ is "locally defined", I must inform $y$ of it's definition (i.e. pass it as an argument). If $c$ is defined as a "global constant", then I don't need to inform $y$ of it's definition (i.e. leave it out of the argument). Is this the "right" train of thought?

Comment: @ThatsRightJack: Yes, you may think of it that way. If $c$ had been previously defined, then it cannot be an input to $y$. If not, then of course $y$ would require $c$ as an input as well otherwise we don't actually have a *mathematical function*.